# F# Data Type Provider ; error on CSVProvider initialization

Tags: f#, f#-data

I am trying to set up a tiny F# console app with FSharp.Data referenced in the solution. I got the following error at runtime :

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Anot_F1.exe
```

for this code (error in line 4) :

```
1 open FSharp.Data
2 type Anot_lines = CsvProvider<"anot1.csv",Separators=";">
3 let ll = Anot_lines.Load("anot1.csv")
4 for r in ll.Rows do
5   printfn "%A" r.ToString
```

In debug mode after line 3, I can see that the variable `ll` contains the proper Headers but does not show the rows.
My CSV file is :

```
tline;tcol;bline;bcol;anot
3;1;4;16;"Barack Obama has ... The US president"
3;1;3;12;"Barack Obama"
3;18;3;26;"ratcheted"
4;102;4;109;"agencies"
4;289;4;306;"financial pressure"
4;1;4;320;"The US president ...ure on the regime"
4;1;4;16;"The US president"
```

I am new to F# and especially have no experience on using type providers.
Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with line 3, you're using a method that loads CSV data from a URL. You need to use the GetSample() method. Also note that the "%A" format placeholder can print any value and doesn't require a ToString() call.

```
let ll = Anot_lines.GetSample()
for r in ll.Rows do
    printfn "%A" r
```

Comment: Thanks Taha but GetSample() does not even load the headers. In debug mode, I get an empty ll variable before the for statement and cannot see Headers anymore.

Comment: ll.Headers returns the headers

Comment: Why are you worried about the headers, they're now strongly typed properties of each row.

Comment: Thanks. I messed up with encoding and file path. I now write directly :let ll = CsvProvider<"filename">.GetSample() as shown in github test file CsvProvider.fs